# webrat have_selector content passes anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, capybara, webrat

My test suite includes RSpec2 with Capybara, Guard, and Spork.  This test passes no matter what I put into `:content`:

```
it 'should something something' do
  rendered.should have_selector('label', :content => "NOWHEREINMYPAGE")
end
```

Am I using this spec wrong? I want to see if there is a `<label>` tag with specific content. Whoops, note that all of the variable assignment and rendering is in a `before :each` block elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have render_views in your spec file.  I just saw this.  And yes that's correct it will look for a tag  with NOWHEREINMYPAGE inside the tags.

Comment: Do I need to do that, though? It's in `specs/views/[model]s/index.html.erb_spec.rb`. I though views were rendered in view specs, and I'm explicitly calling the `render` method (as part of a `before :each` block).

Comment: In the past whenever I was checking the HTML content with have_selector I had to use render_views.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I didn't realize that I had to explicitly put Webrat in my Gemfile. Requiring Webrat resolves the issue, and `render_views` does not need to be present for view tests.